# Renaming files in bulk in PowerShell by attaching current date

Tags: file, powershell, rename, bulk

I searched Stack Overflow and most of the answers I found, are not what I am trying to do. I have multiple files in the directory, that I am trying to rename by attaching the current date and time as a suffix before the extension.

I have done it multiple times on a single file, but cannot get it working for the bulk of files. Here is the code I am using:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.dat" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $curDateTime + $_.Extension }
```

It does not fail, but files are not renamed.

Comment: How have you assigned $curDateTime? For instance, you can't use `:` in a filename.  Does that appear your date/time string?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$curDateTime = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss
Get-ChildItem $Path *.dat -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $curDateTime + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Comment: @keith_hill this worked nicely for me thanks. It helped me organize my photos depending on their timestamps. I started learning powershell and have an [open question](https://superuser.com/questions/1117781/how-to-add-open-with-powershell-to-context-menu-of-folder-object-and-load-prof) not answered yet, please check if you would like to :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.dat" -Recurse |
    ren -New {$_.Name -replace '[.](?!.*?[.])',"_${curDateTime}."} -What
```